# Json file gives 403 error on server

Tags: javascript, json, http-status-code-403

I have a json file contianing data which I access through javascript. On my virtual MAMP server on mac It works, but on my online server when I load the HTML file I cant access the json file from javascript. I get 403 no permission for access error. Why?

Comment: Look at the file permissions and/or ownership, configuration of webserver, double check your file names, etc...Could be a lot of things.

Comment: because you have a permission problem? check your webserver configuration and make sure it's the same as your local host wrt access rights.

Comment: It looks like the file is on readable. That is what 403 means.. Check if file has correct permissions and folders it is in is accessible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your production server is Linux based then please consider these:

1. please check the directory your file is inside. There must be a .htaccess file there, which contains settings regarding directory access. If this is the case, you'll have to either move the json file out of that directory, or disable the .htaccess settings in question.
2. Also, in some cases, you get this error when the file is unreadable for any reason:

   a. file system errors - run fsck;

   b. check file permissions, the file should have at least `644 [rw-r--r--]`, the directory the json file is inside of, should have at least `755 [rwxr-xr-x]` ),

Comment: file permissions are as you said...I cant seem to find the .htaccess file..Does apache control this? problem?

Comment: I know it works..because as I said the same code works on my local mamp/wamp server but not on my real web server...The funny thing is moved my json file into the directory which also has my index.html...now it works...but I cant still access it via data/data.json..though I can acces css or js files in css/style.css and js/map.css in same way

Comment: was the data/ directory created on the server before you uploaded your files? If no, there will be an url or file path error, you may check for leading slashes, lowercase/uppercase filenames and extensions. Linux file system is case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

I just realised that I was getting the same issue because my system.webServer had handlers for ServiceStack to capture all content:

```
<handlers><add path="*" name="ServiceStack.Factory" type="ServiceStack.HttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" resourceType="Unspecified" allowPathInfo="true" /></handlers>
```

But I also had added staticContent to deliver the JSON file extension (Windows8 IIS):

```
<staticContent>
        <remove fileExtension=".json" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/javascript" /></staticContent>
```

When i removed the staticContent, i was getting a 403 error.. but when I add it in, the ServiceStack handler overrides and triggers a 500... perhaps you have something similar? Make sure your config is set up to handle the mimetype.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem.
I noticed in my apache2.conf file there is the following:

```
<Files ~ "\.(env|json|md|gitignore|gitattributes|lock)$">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

That's why it's blocked.
To allow access you need to remove the `json` from there.